# About Build Definition file (XAML) in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

Changes made to build definition file (XAML) takes affect ( shows in build) only when its checked in , is this a normal behavior , What I would like to make all the necessary changes build them and then check it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. TFS gets the xaml file from source control (where else could it get it from?) so you need to check in your changes to the xaml templates.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991344/the-easiest-way-to-test-tfs2010-build-template) post, I have followed the suggestion by J.Reed.

 With that, I always know that my build script is going to work.
I consider this a de-facto best practice.